# Set workbook is failing in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have this simple bit of code which I can not work out why it fails.

The workbook TestData.xlsm is open.

The code is failing on the line Set WBook. It is driving me batty. I need to move on to why I am writing the code. I have tried different code from the internet and everything fails.

The error is:

> Runtime Error 424 Object required.

```
Public Sub specialLookUp()
   Dim WBook As Workbook
   Set WBook = Workbooks(“TestData.xlsm”)
End Sub
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was wrong :( Perhaps your only problem is use of `“`instead of `"` ?

Comment: AT least I am getting a different error, but trying " didn't fix it. For the record @Robin Mackenzie was initially right, I  dropped the .xlsm and am now getting a subscript out of range error, thought the workbook is open.

Comment: @EmptyWaterHoles are you sure the extension of the file is `.xlsm` ? and not `.xlsx` ? maybe you have a space in between "Test Data" , or "Test_Data" ?

Comment: The quotation marks are definitely wrong. Why don't you just start a macro recorder, and switch over to the `TestData` workbook. See what it records, and you have your solution. (It will record `Windows("...")`, but you can change that to `Workbooks("...")` if you like.)

Comment: Yes the quotation marks were a problem. I took your advice of running the macro and it used the full file extension. I also restarted my computer (just in case). The problem is solved. @vacip if you provide your answer as a solution I will accept it.

Comment: @Robin Mackenzie your initial idea of the quotation marks being wrong was a solution too.

Comment: Yep - that is why I deleted the answer because it is totally valid to have the extension in there. It won't be there if you _haven't_ already saved the workbook... I will put in another answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotation marks are a bit odd - can you just try this:

```
Public Sub specialLookUp()
   Dim WBook As Workbook
   Set WBook = Workbooks("TestData.xlsm")
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

It is wrong way. You're missing Open.
Use like this -

```
Set WBook = Workbooks.Open("TestData.xlsm")
```

Comment: OP has stated that `The workbook TestData.xlsm is open.`